# Having trouble accessing an element of an array that is one index less or greater than current index in a for loop(even though it exists)

Tags: javascript, arrays

My object idAry is an array of elements that has an property called `msisdn_id`. There are 4 objects in the array and when I loop through them and the Id is set to be the same as the second ID in the loop, it correctly finds it and falls to the else clause. However, when I try accessing the ids of the elements who is in position +1 or -1 in the array, I get an error of `[Vue warn]: Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'msisdn_id' of undefined"` I have no clue why it's not defined. I'm literally looped through the "left" one.

I have the code like this:

```
  for (let [index, val] of idAry.entries()) {
    console.log("index is:" + index);
    console.log("val[index].msisdn_id:" + val[index].msisdn_id);
    if(id == val[index].msisdn_id){
      console.log("id found:" + val[index].msisdn_id);
      if( index == 0 ){
        //no left button
        console.log("index == 0: " + val[index + 1].msisdn_id);
        this.rightId = val[index + 1].msisdn_id;
      }
      else if (index == (val.length - 1)) {
        //no right button
        console.log("else if: " + val[index - 1].msisdn_id);
        this.leftId = val[index - 1].msisdn_id;
      } 
      else {
        console.log("both LR: " + val[index - 1].msisdn_id + "," + val[index + 1].msisdn_id);
        this.leftId = val[index - 1].msisdn_id;
        this.rightId = val[index + 1].msisdn_id;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```

output looks like:

```
length of ary is:4
TerminalProfileReport.vue?3387:400 index is:0
TerminalProfileReport.vue?3387:401 val[index].msisdn_id:111
TerminalProfileReport.vue?3387:400 index is:1
TerminalProfileReport.vue?3387:401 val[index].msisdn_id:222
TerminalProfileReport.vue?3387:403 id found:222
```

edit - updated the output. it should show `val[index]` and updated code looks like this

```
    for (let [index, val] of idAry.entries()) {
    console.log("index is:" + index);
    console.log("idAry[index].msisdn_id:" + val.msisdn_id);
    if(id == val.msisdn_id){
      console.log("id found:" + val.msisdn_id);
      if( index == 0 ){
        //no left button
        console.log("index == 0: " + idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id);
        this.rightId = idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id;
      }
      else if (index == (idAry.length - 1)) {
        //no right button
        console.log("else if: " + idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id);
        this.leftId = idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id;
      } 
      else {
        console.log("both LR: " + idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id + "," + idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id);
        this.leftId = idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id;
        this.rightId = idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```

Comment: your update is my first answer. and **please give us a partial example of the idAry table, it would be clearer!** AGAIN !

Comment: @MisterJojo I'm not working 24/7...Thank you for your previous answer, I was indeed interpreting it incorrectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you confuse `val` with `idAry`, `val[index].msisdn_id` does not exist use `val.msisdn_id`

```
for (let [index, val] of idAry.entries())
  {
  console.log("index is:" + index);
  console.log("val.msisdn_id:" + val.msisdn_id);


  if( id == val.msisdn_id)
    {
    console.log("id found:" + val.msisdn_id);
    if( index == 0 )
      {
      //no left button
      console.log("index == 0: " + idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id);
      this.rightId = idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id;
      }
    else if (index == (idAry.length - 1)) 
      {
      //no right button
      console.log("else if: " + idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id);
      this.leftId = idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id;
      } 
    else
      {
      console.log("both LR: " + val[index - 1].msisdn_id + "," + val[index + 1].msisdn_id);
      this.leftId = idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id;
      this.rightId = idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id;
      }
    break;
    }
  }
```

but there is much simplier to do
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex

```
let index = idAry.findIndex(e=>e.msisdn_id===id)

if (index!=-1)  // if exist
  {
  console.log('id found , index is', index, idAry[index].msisdn_id);

  if ( index > 0 )
    { this.leftId  = idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id;}

  if (index < (idAry.length - 1))
    { this.rightId = idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id; }
  }
else
  {
  console.log('id not found (', id , ')' );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the code you posted is the same as the one you used since one of the logs you mentioned starts with: `idAry[index].msisdn_id`: while it's in the question `val[index].msisdn_id:`. Anyway based in the code mentioned in the question the issue seems to be in how you use the variable `val` as it's the array itself. In each iteration `val` represents the value of one of the entries in the array `idAry`. 
Here your code updated:

```
for (let [index, val] of idAry.entries()) {
    console.log("index is:" + index);
    console.log("idAry[index].msisdn_id:" + val.msisdn_id);
    if(id == val.msisdn_id){
      console.log("id found:" + val.msisdn_id);
      if( index == 0 ){
        //no left button
        console.log("index == 0: " + idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id);
        this.rightId = idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id;
      }
      else if (index == (idAry.length - 1)) {
        //no right button
        console.log("else if: " + idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id);
        this.leftId = idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id;
      } 
      else {
        console.log("both LR: " + idAry[index - 1].msisdn_id + "," + idAry[index + 1].msisdn_id);
        this.leftId = val[index - 1].msisdn_id;
        this.rightId = val[index + 1].msisdn_id;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
```